# Notify parent component as soon as event occurs in child event?

Tags: vue.js

I need that when a user clicks a button on the child component the parent component receives `cart.lenght` to be assigned the `count` property of an element.

## Child component code

```
<q-btn flat round color="faded" icon="fas fa-shopping-cart" @click="cart(item.id)"/>

cart: function (Id) {
      let cart = []
      cart.push(Id)
      this.$emit('totalItensCart')
      this.$q.localStorage.set('cart', cart)
}
```

***How do I display the `cart.length` value in the `count` property that is in the parent component?***

## Parent component code

```
 <q-route-tab
        count="5"
        icon="fas fa-cart-plus"
        to="/cart"
        exact
 slot="title"/>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per the [vue event documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html), we want to emit an event from the child component to the parent component. You are correct with the `this.$emit` method, but it can take two parameters in order to pass data, like so:

```
this.$emit("name", data);
```

So, let's emit a count of the number of items in the cart from the **first child**:

```
this.$emit("cartUpdate", cart.length);
```

---

Now we need to handle this in the parent. We'll first need a `data` property to keep track of the `totalCartItems` in the **parent**:

```
data: function () {
    return {
        totalCartItems: null
    }
}
```

Assuming that both of your code snippets are in *different* children of the *same* parent, and that the first child (the one that emits `cartUpdate`) has the component name `first-child`:

```
<first-child @cartUpdate="cartUpdate"></first-child>
```

This will call the `cartUpdate()` method in the parent component whenever the child emits an event called `cartUpdate` (using the [`@` shorthand for `v-on`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-on-Shorthand)). The method is very simple, only updating the `totalCartItems` data property in the parent:

```
cartUpdate: function (totalCartItems) {
    this.totalCartItems = totalCartItems;
}
```

---

Finally, let's ensure this gets updated in the second child component by binding it to the data value:

```
<q-route-tab
        :count="totalCartItems"
        icon="fas fa-cart-plus"
        to="/cart"
        exact
 slot="title"/>
```

Comment: I have been using the quasar-framework which is based on VueJs, I had to add `<router-view @ cartItensLength = "setCartLength" @ favoriteItensLength = "setFavoriteLength" />` because it was actually a page of mine!
I can learn a lot from your post, it was a big help, thank you!

Comment: @Sam Holmes Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52285601/how-can-i-add-notification-automatic-after-add-to-cart-in-the-vue-component